# Assign Ids dynamically to Apex:inputField

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, visualforce-component, dynamic-visualforce

I'm trying to assign Id to my inputField dynamically, those input fields are coming from field sets.
These Ids needs to be assigned to those fields which are required in database.

On giving Id dynamically I'm getting **Literal value is required for attribute id in**  error.

Based on those ids I need to perform some check in javascript, before saving the record.

```
<apex:outputPanel id="mySalesforceFields">
  <apex:repeat value="{!fieldSetMemberList}" var="field">
    <apex:inputField value="{!sObject[field]}" required="{!if((field.dbRequired || field.required), true,false)}" 
    id="{!if((field.dbRequired || field.required), field.label,'')}" />

  </apex:repeat>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: Why do you think you need it? You may wish to read up on what an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) is and describe what you are trying to achieve at a higher level.

Answer (score 4):

You can't dynamically assign the Visualforce `id` attribute. You can, however, assign `data-` attributes or pass through `html-` attributes. See, for example, [Setting Custom HTML Attributes on Visualforce Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_html_features_pass_through_attributes.htm)
. Make sure you use a unique value such as the field's API Name rather than its Label if you decide to pass through an `html-id`.

Probably better to use `data-` attributes. You can still select on them.

```
<apex:inputField ... html-data-id="{!field}"
    html-data-required="{!OR(field.required, field.dbRequired)}" />
```